# Встречено "else", а ожидался оператор. 22 строка

Tags: pascal

```
unit labs;
interface
uses crt;
procedure lb;
procedure lb2;
procedure lb3;
implementation
procedure lb1;
 var p,x:real;
begin
textbackground(white);
textcolor(black);
clrscr;
writeln('Введите значение x u p');
write('x=');readln(x);
write('p=');readln(p);
if (2*p*x)>=0 then
   if (sqrt(2*p*x)+3.5*x*x-10)>=0 then
      if (2*p-6*x+1)>0 then
         if cos(abs(2*p-6*x+1)-1)<>0 then
             writeln('C=', sqrt(sqrt(2*p*x)+3.5*x*x-10)/sqr(cos(abs(ln(2*p-6*x+1))-1)):4:4);
         else writeln('Знаменатель меньше нуля');
      else writeln('Основание логарифма меньше нуля');
      
   else writeln('Подкоренное выражение меньше нуля');
else writeln('Подкоренное выражение меньше нуля');
repeat until keypressed;        


procedure lb2;
var i:integer;
x:array[1..100] of real;
p:array[1..100] of real;
d:array[1..100] of real;
r:array[1..100] of integer;
begin
textbackground(white);
textcolor(black);
clrscr;
writeln('Введите количество пар');
readln(i);
for i:=1 to i do begin
    writeln('Введите x u p');
    write('x=');readln(x[i]);
    write('p=');readln(p[i]);
end;
clrscr;
for I:=1 to i do
    if (2*p[i]*x[i])>=0 then
       if (sqrt(2*p[i]*x[i])+3.5*x[i]*x[i]-10)>=0 then
          if (2*p[i]-6*x[i]+1)>0 then
             if cos(abs(2*p[i]-6*x[i]+1))<>0 then
                d[i]:=sqrt(sqrt(2*p[i]*x[i])+3.5*x[i]*x[i]-10)/sqr(cos(abs(ln(2*p[i]-6*x[i]+1))-1))
             else r[i]:=1
          else r[i]:=2
       else r[i]:=3
    else r[i]:=3;
if i>0 then
begin
     writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
     writeln('|||   X   |||   P   |||   C    |||            Примечание            ||| ');
     writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
end;
for i:=1 to i do
    begin
         if r[i]=0 then
            begin
                 writeln('|||  ',x[i]:2:2,' |||  ',p[i]:2:2,' |||  ',d[i]:2:2,' |||                                   |||');
                 writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
            end;
         if r[i]=1 then
            begin
                 writeln('|||  ',x[i]:2:2,' |||  ',p[i]:2:2,' |||        |||       Знаменатель меньше нуля      |||');
                 writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
            end;
         if r[i]=2 then
            begin
                 writeln('|||  ',x[i]:2:2,' |||  ',p[i]:2:2,' |||        |||  Основание логарифма меньше нуля  |||');
                 writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
            end;
         if r[i]=3 then
            begin
                 writeln('|||  ',x[i]:2:2,' |||  ',p[i]:2:2,' |||        ||| Подкоренное выражение меньше нуля |||');
                 writeln('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
            end;
    end;
gotoxy(27,20);
textcolor(100);
writeln('Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода ');
readkey;  end;
  
procedure lb3;
 var N,i,k,Nx,Np,r,m,g,NumOfStrWithMaxMul:                        integer;
var Hx,Hp,A,B,x1,x2,p1,p2,maxMult,currMult,cont:    real;
var x:                                      array [1..10] of real;
var p:                                      array [1..10] of real;
var C:                                      array [1..10,1..10] of string;


BEGIN
ClrScr;
 textcolor(Cyan);

 writeln('Введите  x1,x2:');
 read(x1,x2);
 writeln('Введите шаг Hx');
 read(Hx);
 writeln('Введите  p1,p2');
 readln(p1,p2);
 writeln('Введите шаг Hp');
 readln(Hp);
 ClrScr;



if (((Hx>0) and (x1<x2)) or ((Hx<0) and (x1>x2))) then
     if  ((Hp>0) and (p1<p2)) or ((Hp<0) and (p1>p2)) then
              begin
              Nx:=round(abs((x2-x1)/Hx+1));
              Np:=round(abs((p2-p1)/Hp+1));
              end
  else
      writeln('Ошибка !');
      else writeln('Ошибка !');

if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
  for i:=0 to (Nx-1) do
      x[i+1]:=x1+Hx*i;
if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
  for k:=0 to (Np-1) do
      p[k+1]:=p1+Hp*k;

if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
 for i:=1 to Nx do
     for k:=1 to Np do
      begin


           if ((2*p[k]*x[i])<0) then C[i,k]:=('*   ')
           else if (2*p[k]-6*x[i]+1<=0) then C[i,k]:=('**  ')
           else if (sqrt(2*p[k]*x[i])+3.5*x[i]*x[i]-10<0) then C[i,k]:=('*   ')
           else if (sqr(cos(abs(ln(2*p[k]-6*x[i]+1)-1)))=0) then C[i,k]:=('*** ')
           else
             begin
                  B:=sqr(cos(abs(ln(2*p[k]-6*x[i]+1)-1)));
                  A:=sqrt(sqrt(2*p[k]*x[i])+3.5*x[i]*x[i]-10);
                  str((A/B):1:1, C[i,k]);
             end;

      end;
  textcolor(green);
  write('x  ');
  textcolor(blue);
  write('p ');



if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
  for k:=1 to Np do
  write(p[k]:2:2,'   ');
  writeln;


                              if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
   for i:=1 to Nx do
       begin
       textcolor(green);
       write(x[i]:2:2,' ');
       textcolor(Magenta);

        for k:=1 to Np do
         write(C[i,k]:4,'   ');
         writeln;
       end;



writeln;
writeln;
writeln('* - под корнем отрицательное число ');
writeln('** - под логарифмом отрицательное число');
writeln('*** -  деление на 0');

currMult:=1;
if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
for i:=1 to Nx do
    begin
    for k:=1 to Np do
        begin
        if ((C[i,k] <> '*   ') and (C[i,k] <> '**  ') and (C[i,k] <> '*** ')) then
            begin
            val(C[i,k], cont, N);
            currMult:=currMult*cont;
            end;
        end;
    if (currMult >= maxMult) then
        begin
        maxMult:=currMult;
        NumOfStrWithMaxMul:=i;
        end;
    currMult:=1;
    Writeln;
    end;
if (Nx<=10) and (Np<=10) then
  for k:=1 to Np do
      write(c[numofstrwithmaxmul,k],'');
if (Nx>10) or (Np>10) then
writeln('ошибка введенного диапазона');
  repeat until(keypressed); 
end;
End.
```

Answer (score 1):

В Паскале после выражения, стоящего после `then`, [нельзя](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/Operators/if.html) ставить точку с запятой, а у Вас она стоит.

```
if cos(abs(2*p-6*x+1)-1)<>0 then
 writeln('C=', sqrt(sqrt(2*p*x)+3.5*x*x-10)/sqr(cos(abs(ln(2*p-6*x+1))-1)):4:4); // <- вот она
else writeln('Знаменатель меньше нуля');
```

Сразу скажу, что в других строках для процедуры `lb1` такая же проблема.

UPD: заметил ещё, что в начале прописана процедура `lb`, а не `lb1`